# Conditional Survival Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint distribution $F(x,y)$. Let $F(y|x)=P(Y\leq y|X=x)$ denote the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$. Let $S(y|x)=P(Y>y|X=x)$ the conditional survival function. Does $S(y|x)=1-F(y|x)$ for all $x,y\in R$ is true always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   The Law of Complements asserts that $\mathsf P(Y>y\mid X=x) ~=~ 1-\mathsf P(Y\leq y\mid X=x)$ and every thing else follow from how you defined the functions.

- Let $F(y\mid x) := \mathsf P(Y\leq y\mid X=x)$
- Let $S(y\mid x) := \mathsf P(Y>y\mid X=x)$
- Then $S(y\mid x) $ $= \mathsf P(Y>y\mid X=x) \\ = 1-\mathsf P(Y\leq y\mid X=x)\\ = 1-F(y\mid x)$

Where lies your doubt?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is always true. Conditional distribution is just another distribution which share all the common properties that "ordinary" distribution possess.